# Automation of tasks with argparse Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Hi is anyone able to help. I am learning to use argparse and i want to use the command to call the school.py as school start for example. I have this so far but struggling to handle the arguments. Am i doing this right or what am i doing totally wrong?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This allows quick opening of applications used within the school day")

parser.add_argument("start", help="This will open all the standard applications used within the school day.")
parser.add_argument("engine", help="This will show the Engineering folder within Documents")
parser.add_argument("bus", help="This will show the Business folder within Documents")
parser.add_argument("cs", help="This will show the Computer Science folder within Documents")
parser.add_argument("python", help="This will open the PyCharm application")

args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == "engine":
            engineering()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "cs":
            computer_science()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "python":
            python()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "bus":
            business()
        elif sys.argv[1] == "start":
            std_day()
except:
    print("An error has occurred")
```

My error is

```
usage: autoSchoolDay.py [-h] start engine bus cs python
```

autoSchoolDay.py: error: the following arguments are required: engine, bus, cs, python

Comment: you are adding multiple arguments called "start", "engine", etc. when you need to add a single argument which can be one of "start", "engine", etc. like this: `parser.add_argument('command', choices=['start', 'engine', 'bus', 'cs', 'python'], default='start')` and then you'd do `if args.command == "engine":` and so on.

Comment: Yes i want to call it like ``school start`` or ``school engine``

Comment: How are you calling this script?  From a OS shell?  WIth what commandline arguments?  Or do you even know what we mean by command line arguments?

Comment: @JamesMcC please try the code I added to my comment, I understand what you want.

Comment: Mac OS ZSH with ``school start`` or ``school engine`` etc

Comment: @Boris How does that work

Comment: @JamesMcC it works the way you want :) . It creates one argument "slot" where you can put one of the strings in `choices` and then `args.command` will contain that string.

Comment: If using `argparse` you shouldn't need to parse `sys.argv` directly.  However, the logic defined for your parser is different from your handling of `sys.argv`.

Comment: I think that i should confirm that ``school`` is the name of the executable ``.py`` file @Boris solution to me is wanting me to call ``[python file name] school engine`` whereas what i want to call is ``[python file name] engine``

Comment: Even better would be to use subparsers for this, but I don't think you need that quite yet https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: @Boris You are correct. This is just for a basic solution as i want to improve my python skill and also to stop having to open multiple applications every time i turn my mac on

Comment: @JamesMcC please try the code in my first comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This allows quick opening of applications used within the school day")

parser.add_argument('command', choices=['start', 'engine', 'bus', 'cs', 'python'])

args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    if args.command:
        if args.command == "engine":
            engineering()
        elif args.command == "cs":
            computer_science()
        elif args.command == "python":
            python()
        elif args.command == "bus":
            business()
        elif args.command == "start":
            std_day()
except Exception as e:
    print("An error has occurred", e)
```

Comment: This works and now i get it. Question though. How can i make the help section now if all the commands are combined into one

Comment: You are not the first person who has wanted to do what you want to do. You can find other people asking about this on stack overflow or tutorials on the internet, the keyword is "subcommand". I also linked you to the documentation for what you should try using in a comment.